# ggplot group argument not working. Error code when argument is fulfilled

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two very large data frames with only a single observation in them. I am trying to use the code below to make a line graph. When I run it, however, I get the error ````geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?```

```
mf1.2_Beaver <- data.frame(total_cost16q1 = 1
                           total_cost16q2 = 3
                           total_cost16q3 = 4
                          total_cost16q14= 5
                           total_cost17q1 = 7
                           total_cost17q2 = 8
                           total_cost17q3 = 9
                          total_cost17q14= 10)
mf2.2_Beaver <- data.frame(total_cost16q1 = 5
                           total_cost16q2 = 4
                           total_cost16q3 = 3
                          total_cost16q14= 1
                          total_cost17q1 = 7
                           total_cost17q2 = 8
                           total_cost17q3 = 9
                          total_cost17q14= 10)
 
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q1', y= total_cost16q1, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q2', y= total_cost16q2, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q3', y= total_cost16q3, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q4', y= total_cost16q4, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q1', y= total_cost17q1, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q2', y= total_cost17q2, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q3', y= total_cost17q3, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf1.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q4', y= total_cost17q4, group = 1, col = 'Y1'), linetype=1) +
  
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q1', y= total_cost16q1, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q2', y= total_cost16q2, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q3', y= total_cost16q3, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2016Q4', y= total_cost16q4, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q1', y= total_cost17q1, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q2', y= total_cost17q2, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q3', y= total_cost17q3, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1) +
  geom_line(data = mf2.2_Beaver, mapping = aes(x= '2017Q4', y= total_cost17q4, group = 2, col = 'Y2'), linetype=1)
```

I wish to have a line graph. I have run this type of group before but have never received the error code for the group aesthetic when the argument is fulfilled.

Comment: Becky could you update your question to ask some sample data?

Comment: I just made some changes to it

Comment: The data you provided is not valid R code, there should be commas between columns. Dies it really go "q1", "q2","q3", "q14" in the data? Why not just "q4"? You will need to reshape your data. Points along a line need to be in different rows, not different columns when using `ggplot`.

Comment: Said differently becky_45, it's clear that you aren't attempting the code that you give us, which means that if/when we find problems (such as the parsing errors above), we sometimes have to wonder if your problem is that you have bad code-parsing, bad data, or something else. If you want actionable help with code that has a high likelihood of working on your real data, then it is generally best to (a) provide representative sample data, which means classes/types are all the same; and (b) attempt the code you give us, to remove such ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably bind the rows first, then pivot:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mf1.2_Beaver %>%
  bind_rows(mf2.2_Beaver, .id = "Series") %>%
  mutate(Series = paste0("Y", Series)) %>%
  rename_with(~gsub("total_cost", "20", .x)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Series) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, group = Series, color = Series)) +
  geom_line(linewidth = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_color_manual(NULL, values = c("orangered", "deepskyblue4")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Total cost", title = "Total cost per quarter 2016-17")
```

[image]